# How should I adjust my partition layout so I can update Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, gpt

When I upgraded my PC I installed Windows 10 on a new disk with the old disk still inserted. This meant the new install did not get a system reserved/boot partition. I fixed that by manually creating one, but I am now getting an issue when trying to install `kb4480116`. I get error `0x800f0922` - one cause of this error is when "you have less than 500 MB in system reserved partition"

**My layout:**

```
Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset   *NOTE*
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    Reserved            16 MB  1024 KB  My MSR Partition
Partition 3    Primary            500 MB    17 MB  My EFI Partition
Partition 2    Primary            465 GB   517 MB  My C:
```

**Default layout:** [shown here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/images/dep-win10-partitions-uefi.png)

Microsoft page on this topic [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions).

Should I swap the EFI (system) partition and MSR partition over?
Should I create a recovery partition?

Thanks!